# pattern matching and unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, c#-8.0

I do:

```
(bool success, string name1, string name2) MyFunc() {
  if (DateTime.Now.Year > 2020) return (false, "", ""); // error 
  return (true, "some value", "some value");
}
```

My coding style is to try and deal with errors first, I tried:

```
void f() {
  if (MyFunc() is (false, var name1, var name2)) return;
  Console.WriteLine(name1);
}
```

I get

> Error CS0165  Use of unassigned local variable 'name1'

in the `Console.WriteLine`

This works:

```
void f() {
  if (!(MyFunc() is (true, var name1, var name2)))) return;
  Console.WriteLine(name1);
}
```

I am trying to understand why this is so ? since MyFunc() is called, the result tuple is available, why doesn't the compiler assign it and let me use it ?

This would have been an extremely useful way of returning status+result, is there a point in requesting that feature ?

Comment: Your first issue is that `MyFunc` doesn't have a `return`.

Comment: oopst fixed....

Comment: You'll have to declare `name1` and `name2` before the `if` with a default value, I suspect.

Comment: @John But then it's going to try to match the default values.  I don't think you can do pattern matching and deconstruction at the same time.

Comment: @juharr You may well be right. I've never attempted that myself! :-)

Comment: Actually if you define the variable before hand it complains that it has to be a constant value.

Comment: I think you'll have to to deconstruct it first and then test the value.  You can do something like `if(MyFunc() is (false, _, _))` to ignore the other values, but since you need one of them it looks like you should deconstruct it first `var (success, name1, _) = MyFunc();`

Comment: thx juharr .. my whole purpose was to avoid that ..

Comment: So what you can do is something like `if(MyFunc() is var x && !x.success) return;` and then `Console.WriteLine(x.name1);` But then you're really just dealing with the un-exploded tuple.

Comment: yeah that works, maybe you can put than in an answer .. I am still wondering why my code fails ?

Comment: My guess is that you code fails because of if the first element of the tuple `success` is `true` then c# just won't try to make the following assignments shortcircuiting the expression, as it is done with `&&`

Comment: @pix, it's ugly/unreadable to you because you're not used it, to me it is more readable than the syntax using `out` because it has all the output on the left of the function name and only input on the right

Comment: What about creating a dedicated object/scruct or what ever to order your data on a specific purpose? @kofifus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
void f() {
  if (MyFunc() is (var success, var name1, var name2) && !success) return;
  Console.WriteLine(name1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`name1` and `name2` will only be assigned if return value `MyFunc()` matches the pattern. And, in that case, the method returns.

So, `Console.WriteLine(name1);` will only be executed if `MyFunc()` doesn't match the pattern. And, in that case, `name1` and `name2` won't be assigned.

This will work:

```
void f()
{
    (var error, var name1, var name2) = MyFunc();
    if (error) return;
    Console.WriteLine(name1);
}
```

- [C# variables definite assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#definite-assignment)
- [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

  - [The `is` type pattern expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression)
  - [`when` clauses in `case` expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions)

Comment: but to determine if the return value matches MyFunc has to run which means all results are available .. or am I missing something ?

Comment: The results are available, but if the match doesn't succeed, the variables aren't assigned.

Comment: this adds an unnecessary error variable, see my edited question for a better solution .. still my question is to get a good explanation on why

Comment: See [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCsDetE8QCgCMB7IgG0QGcBXAYxoFMKKAaZCABkQDsBDAW3oRWIDt370wASkQBZAJ4gArHknZcWGLi2IAlgDN8AER4AXegBUdAgHQA5IgHdrATXo8ATogB8iMOz/SIADs+Ho8pBT0rABE0THRkgDciAD0KYj07u5EnmrayCF4Ju5UUYjRFEQCiABu4aVx5ZXVdaQNSXmIAL6dIAAsiHoqnRr5OPr48koquhSh4ZGsdZ68AkK1HmICUoFBiZ1aIgCceNFmFCYJ+5q4PTB3QA===) to see that the compiler doesn't do what you think it does with your code.

Comment: something a bit more wordy focusing on the why rather than other ways of doing it

Comment: Sorry. Can't do better than that.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

The syntax in this question isn't easy to read so I got confused. Deconstruction is performed as needed, only after the a successful match. This [Sharplab.io example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDesAUAjA9vgDaIDOArgMaUCmppANMhAAyIB2AhgLY0RMhWHHjTABKRAFkAniACs2CVhiJkAdkQARTgBcaAFQCWvAHQA5fAHcTATRqcATogB8iMC3eIA/Imw6H5DRMAEQAgsEhAELBEgBciDoAFg5WHDSWiKEOAObkvOw6AKIAHrQADjqG+OyKANywAL6wsCAALIgAZoqYsKqGHb4y8t2GpL4dnESkQYgAbo7CvPxzC1y84kq9qtuqggCc2Gt8YvUqO9sgaqfbTTC3DUA===) shows that this :

```
void f() {
  if (MyFunc() is (false, var name1, var name2)) {
        Console.WriteLine(name1);
        return;
   }
}
```

Is converted to this in Release mode:

```
private void f()
{
    ValueTuple<bool, string, string> valueTuple = MyFunc();
    if (!valueTuple.Item1)
    {
        string item = valueTuple.Item2;
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Instead of trying to check for failure, check for *success* and use the variables :

```
void f() {
  if (MyFunc() is (true, var name1, var name2)) {
      Console.WriteLine(name1);
  }
}
```

Or widen the scope, by using a variable outside the block :

```
var (success,name1,name2)= MyFunc();
if (!success) return;
Console.WriteLine(name1);
```

Or use switch statements :

```
switch(MyFunc()) {
    case (false, _,):
        return ;
    case (success, var name1,var name2):
        Console.WriteLine(name1);        
        break;
}
```

You can also define individual variables and take advantage of the fact that assignments are expressions, but that gets ugly :

```
bool success;
string name1;
string name2; 

if ( ((success,name1,name2)=MyFunc()) is (false,_,_)) {
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(name1);
```

Comment: If is really a scoping issue hiw come `if(MyFunc() is var x && !x.success) return;` and then `Console.WriteLine(x.name1);` works ?

Comment: Why don't you use the clean syntax? You've posted several convoluted samples in the two almost duplicate questions that I simply got confused. I posted examples that simply work. Now, an `unassigned variable` error is perfectly clear - the compiler has no idea whether those variables are initialized or not

Comment: @kofifus updated with a Sharplab.io example that shows what's actually going on.

Comment: Thank you .. what I dont understand is the why .. in your sharplab.io example the valuetuple is being fully destructed before the if, so why doesnt the compiler let me access its items after ? I am particularly interested in checking for error first and using the result after as this is my general coding style

Comment: I don't know why you edited out the note about it simply being out of scope. It is clearly a scoping issue. Assigning the variable in the pattern matching does so only in the scope of the `if` block.

Answer (score 2):

your bool variable is not instanciated, while strings do.

try this:

```
static (bool success, string name1, string name2) MyFunc()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Year > 2020) return (false, "", "");
        return (true, "some value", "some value");
}

static void f()
{
    if (MyFunc() is var (b, name1,name2) && !b) return;
        Console.WriteLine(name1);
}

public static void Main()
{
    f();
}
```

Comment: or even better `if (!(MyFunc() is (false, var name1, var name2)))) return;` but my question is why not how